# CListView - adding serial number

Tags: yii

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th width="35">S.No.</th>
        <th align="left">Club Member</th>
        <th width="155">Schedule</th>
        <th width="155">Point</th>
    </tr>
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'itemView'=>'_reportSchedule',
        )); ?>
</table>
```

how can i get serial number like 1,2,3, and so on ??

Comment: What do you mean "how can I get"?

Comment: how to display serial number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the view file "_reportSchedule" use this:

```
<?php echo ++$index;?>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but starts from 0, so i user <?php echo ++$index; ?>

Answer (score 0):

In your **_reportSchedule.php** partial view you can echo it out using:

```
echo $data->serial_number;
```

This assumes that serial_number is an attribute of whatever model you are using. As mnetioned by Sudhanshu Saxena, if you simply want the index (the number of the item in the set), use:

```
echo $index
```

This is a zero based numbering system (first record has an index of 0)

Answer (score 0):

just use In the view file "_reportSchedule"

```
$widget->dataProvider->getPagination()->currentPage * $widget->dataProvider->getPagination()->pageSize + $index + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$index` indicates the number of the line starting at `0`, is to display the correct number on all pages need to make calculations:

```
$widget->dataProvider->getPagination()->currentPage * $widget->dataProvider->getPagination()->pageSize + $index + 1
```